# An example of a Cursor & UPDATE statement in conjunction inside a procedure on Redshift

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql, database-cursor

Would you please provide an an example for a Redshift procedure where you have used a cursor and an UPDATE statement in conjunction? Is that even feasible, I couldn't find an example. I'm looking for a simple template code to learn how to have these 2 together in a single procedure on Redshift.

Here is an example use case:

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl 
  (
   Contactid VARCHAR(500), 
   sfdc_OppId_01 VARCHAR(500),
   sfdc_OppId_02 VARCHAR(500),
   sfdc_OppId_03 VARCHAR(500),
   sfdc_OppId_04 VARCHAR(500),
   sfdc_OppId_05 VARCHAR(500),
   sfdc_OppId_06 VARCHAR(500)       
   )
```

I want to update each sfdc_OppId_xx with the relative value from another table; sfdc_tbl. Here  is what sfdc_tbl looks like:

| sfdc_contactId | sfdc_Opp_Id |
| --- | --- |
| AA123hgt | 999999 |
| AA123hgt | 888888 |
| AA123hgt | 777777 |
| AA123hgt | 432567 |
| AA123hgt | 098765 |
| AA123hgt | 112789 |

So as you see, there are duplicate sfdc_contactid in the sfdc_tbl. My final goal is to list all the sfdc_Opp_Id for given contactid horizontally in the test_tbl. I shall not have duplicate contactid in the test_tbl.

```
  INSERT INTO test_tbl (Contactid) 
  SELECT sfdc_contactId
  FROM sfdc_tbl
  GROUP BY sfdc_contactId
```

And here is what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testing_procedure (results INOUT refcursor)
AS 
$$ 
BEGIN 
       OPEN cursor_testing FOR
           SELECT 
                  Ops.sfdc_Opp.id, 
                  ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY Ops.sfdc_contactId ORDER BY sfdc_Opp_Id ) RWN

            FROM sfdc_tbl Ops
            INNER JOIN test_tbl tbl 
            ON Ops.sfdc_contactId = tbl.contactid; 

   UPDATE test_tbl
     SET sfdc_Opp_01 =  CASE WHEN cursor_testing.RWN = 1 THEN cursor_testing.sfdc_Ops_id ELSE NULL END,
         sfdc_Opp_02 =  CASE WHEN cursor_testing.RWN = 2 THEN cursor_testing.sfdc_Ops_id ELSE NULL END,
         sfdc_Opp_03 =  CASE WHEN cursor_testing.RWN = 3 THEN cursor_testing.sfdc_Ops_id ELSE NULL END,
         sfdc_Opp_04 =  CASE WHEN cursor_testing.RWN = 4 THEN cursor_testing.sfdc_Ops_id ELSE NULL END,
         sfdc_Opp_05 =  CASE WHEN cursor_testing.RWN = 5 THEN cursor_testing.sfdc_Ops_id ELSE NULL END,
         sfdc_Opp_06 =  CASE WHEN cursor_testing.RWN = 6 THEN cursor_testing.sfdc_Ops_id ELSE NULL END
         ;
                         

END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I keep getting an error

> incorrect syntax at or near "cursor_testing"

Comment: No comments on the soundness of this method (Bill writes good stuff so listen to him) but the specific problem is that you are not declaring variables, so the cursor is unknown.  Look at "declare" in PL/pgSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered a question with a similar solution.  The SQL uses a cursor's data to INSERT into a table and this same path should work for UPDATE - [How to join System tables or Information Schema tables with User defined tables in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492621/how-to-join-system-tables-or-information-schema-tables-with-user-defined-tables/65500498#65500498)

That being said and looking at your code I really think you would be better off using a temp table rather than a cursor.  The first thing to note is that a cursor is not a table.  Your use pattern won't work AFAIK.  You read a cursor row by row (or bunches) which is contrary to Redshift's columnar table storage.  So you will need to loop on the rows from the cursor and perform N updates.  This will be extremely slow!  You would be querying columnar data, storing the results in a cursor as rows, reading these row one by one, and then performing a new query (UPDATE) for each row.  Ick!  Stay in "columnar land" and use a temp table.

Comment: Many thanks Bill. Your feedback is on point. I realize the cursor approach is not appropriate now. The temp table approach you noted is working.