# How to UNLOAD Redshift permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I tried to unload Redshift permissions to S3 but the function HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE() uses **leader-node** which is incompatible with UNLOAD.

Is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are seeing leader-only data can't be treated like other data on Redshift.  There is a workaround for this inside of Redshift but it is a bit clunky.  You can push your select statement results into a cursor and read this information out of the cursor and into a data table which you can then manipulate like any other data.  This is done in a stored procedure - example for moving a leader-only system table's data to a normal table [How to join System tables or Information Schema tables with User defined tables in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492621/how-to-join-system-tables-or-information-schema-tables-with-user-defined-tables/65500498#65500498)

Alternatively you can have the tool issuing the query just save the result to S3.  This can be a Lambda function or just your bench with a AWS CLI command following.  There are lots of different options when it comes to these "external" options.