# Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a usecase where I needed to join the **pg_tables** with **svv_table_info** and get the column tableowner from pg_tables. While I tried to join both the tables using below query on Redshift , it throws the below error.

**What I need ?**

> I needed the join the svv_table_info and get the **tableowner** col from
> pg_tables

**Query Used:**

```
select a.schema, a.table, b.schemaname , b.tablename ,b.tableowner 
from svv_table_info a 
left join pg_tables b
on a.schema = b.schemaname
and a.table = b.tablename limit 10;
```

**Error:**

> SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: Amazon Invalid operation: Specified types
> or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;

- I have tried to use Cast,Convert and also tried to create a temp table to and access tableowner, nothing worked

Thanks, Gokul

Answer (score 0):

That cryptic error message is Redshift's way of saying that you are using source data from the leader node in combination with data from the compute nodes.  Some system tables only exist on the leader node and you can query them but you cannot (easily) combine them with compute node data as there isn't a path for source data to flow from the leader to the compute nodes during a query.

In this case one of the sources is a leader-only data table and one it a compute node data set. (You can test if a table is leader-only by cross-joining it with a user defined table of one row and see if it produces this error.)  If I'm correct you may be able to resolve this quickly by using different catalog tables that reside at the same part of the cluster.

I wish AWS would document which catalog tables are leader-only so people can stop falling into this trap.

Reach out if more assistance is needed than interpreting the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you please expand on the quick solution you are describing. How can I find a catalog table that resides in the same part of the cluster?

Comment: As I said I wish AWS would document which system tables are leader-node only.  That said making the data from these leader-node tables available for full use on the cluster involves copying their data (or a subset) to a normal table (temp or perm).  There are a number of ways to do this but only one that does it completely within Redshift.  That is to query the table, put the results in a cursor, and then copy the cursor contents to a table.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492621/how-to-join-system-tables-or-information-schema-tables-with-user-defined-tables/65500498#65500498