# Cursors using variables on redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, cursor

I have a table with unique timestamps.

The table name is t1

```
scedtimestamp
2021-09-30 23:45:14 
2021-09-30 23:40:13 
2021-09-30 23:35:14 
2021-09-30 23:30:14 
2021-10-13 07:55:13
```

I need to write a query using cursor on Redshift to compare those timestamps for every 5 mins. something like this :

```
select electricalbus,shadowprice from wm_lmp where scedtimestamp between '2021-09-30 23:45:14' and '2021-09-30 23:50:14'
```

all the dates in the above code need to be replaced with timestamp and timestamp + 5 mins

```
begin;
declare cs cursor for
select distinct scedtimestamp as name from t1
fetch next from cs into temp;

select electricalbus,shadowprice from wm_lmp where scedtimestamp between temp and dateadd(m,5,temp)

close cs;
commit;
```

but my code gives syntax errors says - ERROR: syntax error at or near "into" Position. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you desire to loop on the results of the "select distinct" query.  You don't need a cursor to do this, you just need a row variable and a for loop.  Here's an answer that does this (for a different use case) that might help.

[How to join System tables or Information Schema tables with User defined tables in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492621/how-to-join-system-tables-or-information-schema-tables-with-user-defined-tables/65500498#65500498)

If not can you clarify what result you desire from the stored procedure.