# Redshift Dynamic Masking - using pg_user & pg_group in a compute query

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to implement  dynamic column masking.

AWS provide a simple demo here :
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-redshift-dynamic-data-masking

However, this simply anchors off the current_user function, meaning that you must maintain a record for every single user in your cluster.
It makes more sense to base this on database GROUP.

However, I cannot use pg_user or pg_group in a query that runs on compute nodes !
Anyone got ideas how to work around ?

My originally intended query would have looked like this ...

```
select 
    u.usename 
    ,g.groname
    , c."permission"
from 
  pg_user u
  INNER JOIN 
  pg_group g
  ON u.usesysid = ANY(g.grolist)
  INNER JOIN
  test.sensitive_control c
  ON c."group" = g.groname 
WHERE 
  u.usename = current_user
```

> ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not
> supported on Redshift tables. Warnings: Column "g.grolist" has
> unsupported type "integer[]". Function "name(character varying)" not
> supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define a process that copies pg_user and/or pg_group to a normal table.  This will make the information available to the compute nodes to use.  You can also add information to your versions of these tables to allow for columns that are specifically useful to you.

This copying can be done in several ways but an automatic process that updates the new tables regularly is likely the best route.  As you see there is no direct route from a system table that is only on the leader to the compute nodes for use as a data source so this process will need to work around this.  Here's a few ways you can do this:

1. An external process like a lambda can just read these tables and then write new tables back into the database - select then insert values.
2. Or your SQL can write the pg_user/pg_group contents to S3 and then copy them back into new tables.
3. Or if you don't want the information to leave the database you can
   read these system tables into a cursor and then read the cursor back
   into these new tables.  (I've written a previous answer on doing
   exactly this but reading a cursor is slow so you likely don't want
   to skip the creation of these news tables and just put this process
   in line with your queries.)

Comment: Thanks Bill, half of this is knowing what is NOT possible so you dont waste energy trying. found your previous answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492621/how-to-join-system-tables-or-information-schema-tables-with-user-defined-tables/65500498#65500498