# In Redshift/PLPGSQL stored procedure : how to store the result of show table into a variable to reuse it?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I'm trying to automate the generation of creation table script.

How to deal with this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE talend_retail.generate_sql_create_table_by_name(
    schema_name VARCHAR(100),
    table_name VARCHAR(100),
    year INTEGER
) AS
$$
DECLARE
    query_show_table TEXT := 'SHOW TABLE my_schema.my_table' || year || ';';
    query_result_show_table TEXT;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE query_show_table INTO query_result_show_table;
    RAISE INFO 'result: %', query_result_show_table;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here's the error

> EXECUTE ... INTO can only be used on a SELECT query

Answer (score 0):

SHOW TABLE and a number of other actions generate their results on the leader node on Redshift.  As such there is no "normal" path for the results to flow back to later steps of the process.  The solution is to put the output of these leader-only statements into a cursor and then read that back into a later step.

There are a number of examples of doing this on SO.  Here's one I wrote a while back for joining catalog tables (also leader-only) with normal table data and storing as a normal table.  Very similar to what you are trying to do though I don't suspect you need to loop.  [How to join System tables or Information Schema tables with User defined tables in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492621/how-to-join-system-tables-or-information-schema-tables-with-user-defined-tables/65500498#65500498)