# Redshift RBAC inherited roles

Tags: recursion, amazon-redshift

In redshift, is there a way to traverse the hierarchy in svv_role_grants in order to get all the inherited roles for a given role?

I tried recursive cte but got error

SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

```
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates(role_name,granted_role_name) AS (
SELECT  role_name, granted_role_name
FROM    svv_role_grants
WHERE   role_name in ('role_a','role_b')
UNION ALL
SELECT rg.role_name, rg.granted_role_name
FROM   svv_role_grants rg 
INNER JOIN subordinates s On s.granted_role_name = rg.role_name
)
SELECT * FROM subordinates;
```

Comment: Can you post your query?  I suspect that the issue is that you are using leader-only data with compute node data which isn’t supported.  There are ways to do this inside of Redshift but sometimes it is best to work outside of Redshift for these processes.  Seeing what you are attempting will shed light on how to attack.

Comment: @BillWeiner Added the sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like svv_role_grants (view) uses some leader-only functions in its definition.  I expect this is preventing this data being used in a complex query like a reclusive cte.  So I think you will want to extract the results of this view and then process its contents.

You can do this by selecting the information out of Redshift and then loading it back into Redshift as a normal table or process the information in another tool.  You can query the data and put into a normal table within Redshift but this requires a stored procedure.

I wrote up this process up for another person here - [How to join System tables or Information Schema tables with User defined tables in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492621/how-to-join-system-tables-or-information-schema-tables-with-user-defined-tables/65500498#65500498)